# Could not determine the dependencies of task Could not create task

Tags: java, android, flutter, plugins, gradlew

I want to install the gradle plugin version 7.6

but I get this Error :

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':path_provider_android:test'.

> Could not create task ':path_provider_android:testProfileUnitTest'.
> this and base files have different roots: E:\flutter downloader the main program\flutterdownloaderthemainprogram\build\path_provider_android and C:\Users\Gcc\Downloads\Compressed\flutter_windows_3.3.0-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.22\android.

this is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
          repositories {
            google()
                  mavenCentral()
           }

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
           }
        }

          allprojects {
      repositories {
     google()
              mavenCentral()
             }
         }

           rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
          subprojects {
              project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
                       } 
          subprojects {
               project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
             }

                 task clean(type: Delete) {
              delete rootProject.buildDir
             }
```

I use the java19

I try java17 and java11
I tried diffrent version of the gradle but I get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

-go to the project terminal (ctrl+j in vscode) and run  `flutter clean`

-go to the android folder and delete the .gradle folder

-run `flutter pub get`

-run `flutter run`

Comment: again when I run the < ./gradlew build > I get the same Error